# Jquery select on change not good value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**EDIT: removed unnecessary information**

I want to take select element parent when the select Element value is changed, and I want to serialize the parent:

```
jQuery('body').on('change','.shop_table select',function (){
    memberid = this.value;
    parent = $(this).parent().serialize();
    console.log(parent); // activity%5B9058%5D%5B0%5D=9145
    selector = jQuery(this).find('option:selected');
    console.log(selector.val()); // 9183
});
```

The first output have a value: 9145 and other want, is 9183..

I need to serialize all element in the parent of the selectable element.. (many input and select) but I don't have the good value when I change the value.

What missing?

Any idea?

Comment: `ajaxurl` is not defined?

Comment: yes. it's define.. it's in wordpress variable already defined.

Comment: Well... then you should state that you are using Wordpress.

Comment: @Nicolas: I don't think is A Wordpress issues but just the js pattern. If i remove the ajax section.. I have the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I have found something:

```
jQuery('body').on('change','.shop_table select',function (){
    memberid = this.value;
    parent = $(this).parent().find('select,input').serialize();
    console.log(parent); // activity%5B9058%5D%5B0%5D=9183
    selector = jQuery(this).find('option:selected');
    console.log(selector.val()); // 9183
});
```

The key, is "finding" elements that we need to serialize into.